# Server 08 Print server deploying to server 03

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, print-server

Server 08 R2 setup as a printer server with 300+ printers installed.

I created an empty GPO and enforced it on the OU containing a few servers that are server 03 that I need the printers to be deployed to.

No event logs, Logged in and out, did a gpupdate /force

gpresult shows the GPO is applied at the computer level.

Check the GPO and it's in computer -> policies -> windows settings -> printer connections.

Not sure what I'm missing?

Domain level is 2008 R2

***Update 1***

PushPrinterConnections has been placed in the correct directory under sysvol and added to the user startup script. Logged out and in, also ran it after login and the deployed printer still doesn't show

***Update 2***

Installed client side extensions on the 03 boxes and the printers still aren't coming over.

When I look in the GPO computer -> policies -> windows settings -> printer connections is where the printers are showing but when I edit the GPO this is missing and I have no way to add/remove a printer.

Even when I remove it from print management on the 2008 R2 print server, they stay in the GPO.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? If these are terminal servers and you want users to be able to print, for example, then this is (IIRC) a *per-user* setting in Windows, not a per-machine setting, and these need to be managed via GPO settings applied to users.

Comment: The client side extensions require service pack 2 and XMLLite.  I assume you have both of those, yes?